# Value tuple type pattern

Tags: c#, c#-7.0, valuetuple

I am trying to use a type pattern in C# 7 against a tuple type:

```
var lst = new List<object>();
lst.Add("foo");
lst.Add(("bar","baz"));

foreach (var item in lst) {
    switch (item) { 
        case string s:
            break;
        case (string, string) t: //Compiler error here
            break;
    }
}
```

but the compiler gives me the following error:

> Invalid expression term 'string'
>   A constant value is expected

How can I resolve this?

---

N.B. I know I can use:

```
case ValueTuple<string,string> t:
```

but I am wondering if there is a better syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `case ValueTuple<string, string> t:`.

You just added the same solution to your question while I posted this answer. Well, you'll have to stick with this solution until they add compiler support for the `case (,):` syntax (wouldn't wait for that since this is an edge case).

Answer (score 1):

There are different sorts of patterns which were not implemented in C# 7.0, but are tracked in the [patterns proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/patterns.md#positional-pattern), including recursive and positional patterns that you describe. Some of those are candidate for later 7.x point releases.